# How can I transform geocoding with google in geocoding with Tomtom? (Python?

Tags: python, geocoding, google-geocoding-api, tomtom

I have this code that basically give me the lat and long when I give it the direction. It is planted to use the API of google but now I need to use the Tomtom API. I don´t know how to do it.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
ds_address=('C:/Users...
wb = load_workbook(filename = ds_address)
data = wb['Sheet1']

#########################
######### 02 - API GOOGLE
#########################
import googlemaps
YOUR_API_KEY =
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=YOUR_API_KEY)

def geo_coding_google(adrss):
    geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(adrss)
    lat,lng = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat'],geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return(lat,lng)

#########################
######### 03 - Build Data
#########################
out = []


for r in range(2,101):#42207):
    try:
        id=str(data.cell(row=r, column=1).value).lower().encode('utf-8').strip()
        adrss=str(data.cell(row=r, column=2).value).lower().encode('utf-8').strip()
        adrss=str(adrss)+",medellin,antioquia,colombia"
        print(adrss)
        g_c=geo_coding_google(str(adrss))
        #### Save Data
        out.append({'id':id,'direccion':adrss,'lat':g_c[0],'lon':g_c[1]})

    except IndexError:
        out.append({'id':"NA",'direccion':"NA",'lat':"NA"[0],'lon':"NA"[1]})
        pass


#########################
######### 04 - Export data
#########################

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
file_name="C:/Users
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a library that supports TomTom Geocoding endpoint.
For example: https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/TomTom.html

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> g = geocoder.tomtom(adrss, key='<API KEY>')
>>> result = g.latlng
```